# C programming Sockets recv

Tags: c, sockets

I have made a successful call web request with a socket and printed out the result. This is done with the send and recv method. Now I would like to be able to give a ruff indication of how many bytes are received and how many bytes needs to be downloaded. But I have simply no clue how to achieve this in C.

Code for receiving I have so far is: (I'm not on the computer with the actual code)

```
while ((rev = recv(sockfd, buf, size-1, 0)) > 0) {
    //Print result etc
}
```

Comment: You know how many bytes have been received because as part of reading from the socket, the return value is the number of bytes received in the buffer.  So you just need a counter that starts at zero and then increments by the number of bytes received.  The only way you know how many bytes to be downloaded is for the other end of the socket to tell you.  A socket is just a transport device to move bytes from one place to another.  It does not know anything about the semantics of what is being transported.  Are you using the HTTP protocol?

Comment: Yes I am using the HTTP protocol. But the rev is not the complete amount or isn't this possible?

Comment: You will need some kind of an agreement with the remote end of the connection to provide some kind of data length value.  The HTTP protocol specifies a header followed by data.  However what is in the header will vary depending on the remote application and the kind of HTTP request (GET, POST, etc.) is being sent.  A GET is designed to put the request information into the URI specified in the first line of the header.  A POST from a standard compliant remote application will provide additional directives in the request header including a Content-Length: directive.

Comment: Another point is that TCP/IP is a byte stream transport so you need to know what the byte stream is that the other side is sending.  HTTP header is UTF-8 I believe however after the header end (indicated by an empty line I believe) the rest of the data may or may not be UTF-8 characters.  If there are multiple files in the data stream, there will be a separator string specified in the header as well.  Each `recv()` call only returns the bytes currently received and TCP may introduce delays so that a file of 2K bytes is received in 3 batches of .5K, 1K, and .5K so you must read multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket is limited to packets, it has no clue about what you are downloading.

If you are downloading a file from a web server using HTTP, you can however use the HTTP response header to get the desired information "Content-Length"
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Thus read the first packet and interpret the first bytes of your received data as "HTTP response header" to know how much must be downloaded.

Comment: This is correct Thank you. Now I need to find a way to split the headers from the "actual data"

Comment: A TCP socket is not limited to single packets, it is not limited to packets at all, because TCP is a stream based protocol. So what you get from recv might have been send in multiple packets or you might get the contents of only half a packet (if you specify a small size).

Comment: You are right, i'll change that. But the HTTP content-length will still be the best for an estimate or am I wrong?.

Comment: if the content-lenght is present in the header, it's the exact size of the data you're downloading. However, the server may not send it, and then you'll not know beforehand how much data is coming